# Dapper.NET and IQueryable

Tags: c#, lambda, dapper

Is there a plan to make Dapper.net compatible with IQueryable interfaces? If not, what's the workaround to use Dapper with "Expression Trees" filters?

Comment: Surely a question about the future of Dapper.Net would be better placed on github?

Comment: This is a feature request for an external library.

Comment: At nearly 1,000 reputation, you should know the rules by now.  This is completely offtopic.

Comment: Some may quibble about whether this question satisfies the rules, but it asked a question I was looking for, and the answer was helpful.

Comment: Excellent question, I will be working with Dapper soon, my first question was what is it? and my second question was exactly this one!

Comment: What solution did you end up with Bill? As you might be looking for a faster performing solution then the default EF behavior?

Comment: Any updates to this, given there several years passed by

Comment: Updating this for QuickGrid in 2023. Although it'll work with Dapper I guess there's no point?!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

No, there are no plans to do this. It is far far outside what dapper tries to do. So far that I would say it is antithetical. Dapper *core* tries to be the friend to those who love their SQL.

Comment: Great answer - If any doesnt like SQL, there are other solutions like Entity Framework.

Comment: I really like SQL (or I really like to like SQL). but i also like getting paid early. Screw SQL, i want to deploy. Entity Framework for SQLite it is!

Comment: I'm sorry SQL, I really meant screw OData! Forgive me, I'm crawling back to your arms!

Comment: SQL is faster in the end, not EF 

Comment: @niico Faster to run, certainly. Not always/necessarily faster to build with -- particularly on medium to medium(ish)-sized projects.

Comment: @BrianLacy A matter of taste, experience and it depends how you define 'faster'. With SQL I know exactly what's going on, I'm speaking the language of the database, I take the results and Dapper maps them. Simples. With EF it does all sorts of its own weird joining and data access in an opaque way, often highly inefficiently and highly unpredictably. Not my thing but to each their own.

Comment: @niico indeed, we also need to consider the time spent when EF *doesn't* do what we expect, plus the time spent *finding out* that EF didn't do what we expected (from a symptom like performance reports); this doesn't happen every time, but when it does: it can be a time sink

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Dapper.TQuery NuGet package for that.

Answer (score -6):

You can get `IQueryable` from `IEnumerable` using the built-in extension method  `AsQueryable` in  `System.Linq` namespace

```
public IQueryable<Order> GetOrdersAsQuerable()
{
    IEnumerable<Order> qry= GetOrders(); //using Query<T>
    //use the built-in extension method  AsQueryable in  System.Linq namespace
    return qry.AsQueryable();            
}
```

**Update:**

For effort to support real IQueryable, the project [DbEasyConnect](https://github.com/jacobSpitzer/DbEasyConnect/wiki/LinqExtensions) provide LinqExtensions

Comment: But it won't be a real IQueryable object and so it doesn't have any benefits.

Comment: yes, but you can use the IQueryable version to bind, for example GridView in Asp.net and benefit for sorting (you can't sort using IEnumerable version).

Comment: Sure, it's pretending to be an IQueryable object, but we all know it isn't and AFAIK the benefits of a real IQueryable do not apply if you mock it, right?

Comment: The value of `IQueryable ` in e.g. EF or linq2Sql  is lazy executing to the last minute and generate sql that sent to the server.
but, the story is different in Dapper. In Dapper you do all filters in a parametric sql statement using `Query<POCO>` and get `IEnumerable`.
You gain  extra benefit by using `AsQuerable` and get dynamic sorting that you have to implement it without `AsQuerable`.
see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106802/why-use-asqueryable-instead-of-list#comment8817475_4096467

Comment: This is not the expected behavior JK. seems to want. This is just a cast, JK. seembs to want a EF behavior creating the Query dynamically.