# replacing EF with ado.net

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to remove entity framework from a project. I know there are several ways. But I'm looking for the fastest way.
The first thing I tried was to pass the linq code into a stored procedure and return the data in a list of objects. For that it was necessary to create an object for each stored procedure. but that is taking me a lot of time. So I thought about doing the following

this is the current code

```
var letter = (from doc in context.COB_Letter
                          where doc.iDocumentId == iLetterId
                          select new
                          {
                              iSituation = doc.iSituation
                          });
```

This is the idea I have:

```
var letter = (from doc in customClass.COB_Letter()
                          where doc.iDocumentId == iLetterId
                          select new
                          {
                              iSituation = doc.iSituation
                          });

class customClass {
    public List<COB_Letter> COB_Letter()
    {
        // using stored procedure to retrieve all data from COB_Letter
    }
}
```

It is basically creating a function for each EF model. and return all the data with ado. and use the linq code only for data filtering and more.

but I was wondering is it a good idea? bring all the data from a table and manipulate the information **(linq to datasets)**. because the amount can vary, sometimes it can be 20 records and other times thousands of them. and as I investigated the first version **(linq to entities)** it executes the sql command directly in the database so it is not necessary to bring all the information and then manipulate it. or do you recommend any other alternative? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Removing EF entirely seems quite drastic. Seeing the rest of your question I can hardly imagine that you're better off doing that. Why not just for some specific cases where it (apparently) doesn't match well?

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little confused by your question as EF uses ADO.NET behind the scenes. I would never go back to raw ADO.NET (`DataReader`, `DataTable`, `DataSet`...), I would opt instead for a very performant micro ORM. I'm really fond of DAPPER (https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper), a micro ORM which you are using right now when reading this answer as it is created by and powers StackOverflow.

What it does? It reads entities from the database for you :-) This is a step you would normally do manually with raw ADO.NET, which is tedious and error prone. With dapper you create POCO (Plain Old C# Object) classes, write your own SQL statements (for me it's a plus to be able to control the exact SQL that's going to hit the database rather than relying on some ORM magic), and Dapper will hydrate your objects for you (to hydrate an object means "filling it with data").

There are many other micro ORMs around, but I'm mostly familiar with Dapper and I've been using it in production critical code for years. I used to use full fledged ORMs like EF, NHibernate and DevExpress's XPO, but I gained a lot of performance switching to Dapper. I took an incremental step to "remove" the ORMs from my codebase: I took the classes already used in those ORMs, removed any code/attributes/logic which were ORM-dependent, moved business logic out of the classes themselves, letting in only the intrinsic validations and basic calculations (e.g., Age is calculated from BirthDay, Name must not be null, etc.) Then I organized it in Repository classes which returns collections or single values stored on these "light-weight" classes.

You must certainly have classes representing the tables already as you are using Entity Framework. You can keep using these classes if they are POCO (plain Old C# Objects) without attached EF logic, or business logic inside. If not, just duplicate them, remove the EF-related code and/or internal business logic, and stick a Dto suffix (Data Transfer Object) on the class: `Person` -> `PersonDto`. Now create a `Repository` class and write methods to retrieve data using Dapper, returning `IEnumerable<PersonDto>` for queries which return collections, etc.

An example of how easy it is to use Dapper (blatantly taken from their homepage):

```
public class Dog
{
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float? Weight { get; set; }

    public int IgnoredProperty { get { return 1; } }
}

var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
var dog = connection.Query<Dog>("select Age = @Age, Id = @Id", new { Age = (int?)null, Id = guid });

Assert.Equal(1,dog.Count());
Assert.Null(dog.First().Age);
Assert.Equal(guid, dog.First().Id);
```

Edit - per some comments I'll explain the difficulties of using LINQ without a full-fledged ORM

You've hit the nail in the head when you said:

> is it a good idea? bring all the data from a table and manipulate the
> information (linq to datasets)

Because it's a really bad idea! Part of what you get for (nearly) free with EF is that your LINQ queries get translated by some really smart and advanced voodoo magic into SQL. All data filtering happens at the database level. This means that the database retrieves only the data you need, and that's what a DB is meant to do! It isn't just a persistence store!

If you get all your data from the DB with a stored procedure, and then apply LINQ to objects locally (inside your app) you're wasting lots of resources on way too many levels:

1. You're wasting memory as all data must be materialized
2. You're wasting network resources as all your data must be sent over the wire to your app
3. Your throughput will suffer tremendously
4. You're wasting all your carefully designed database indexes which makes querying the DB fast and efficient as they won't be used by your "in-app" LINQing and will be wasted when retrieving all the data all the time

If you are shying away from learning SQL by using LINQ, then I really urge you to stick to Entity Framework, as it has become a very mature product, and with a properly designed object model it won't perform bad! In fact they've made strides to make it almost as fast as micro-ORMs like Dapper in their most recent releases. But, then, you'll have to switch to .NET 7 or 8 to reap most of the benefits.

The problem now lies here: "properly designed object model". To properly design your Object Model to work well with EF + Sql Server you MUST know SQL!

> No amount of ORM voodoo can shield you away from SQL!

Learning SQL will make you avoid common pitfalls that many OO people fall into when using an ORM. It's not a silver bullet! There isn't one! That's why Dapper is a plus from me as I still write my own optimized SQL, but I don't have to handle object hydration myself. I would write your code as follows:

```
    public static COB_Letter GetLetter(IDbConnection conn, long iLetterid) {
        return conn.QuerySingleOrDefault<COB_Letter>(
            "SELECT * FROM COB_Letter WHERE iDocumentId = @iLetterId", 
            new { iLetterid });
    }
```

Comment: This makes me happy :p

Comment: @MarcGravell your comment honors me, sir! Happy new year.

Comment: I do agree that Dapper is a gem, but they want to "use the linq code only for data filtering and more". I think that's a big challenge when dropping EF if they don't want to pull entire tables into memory. They would need a reliable (i.e. maintained, multiple contributors, no "potholes") third-party library that translates `IQueryable` expressions into SQL. But AFAIK there are none, and I think Marc still wants to [adhere to the concept](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27588877/861716) (I would). Therefore, I don't really see how just Dapper could fit the bill. Would be nice to hear from OP.

Comment: @GertArnold "use the linq code only for data filtering and more" is really a very difficult requirement to even understand. If the OP wants to keep using the benefits of a full fledged ORM like LINQing directly to the database, then why remove EF? I could only answer with my honest advice: don't try to hide SQL behind ORM voodoo :-) Write your SQL, hydrate your objects with a good micro-ORM and be happy. THe OP could check something like https://github.com/DotNetBrightener/LinQ-To-Sql-Builder which builds SQL out of LINQ...

Answer (score -1):

Removing Entity Framework from a project is a significant decision, and choosing the right alternative depends on various factors. Your proposed approach of using stored procedures for data retrieval and then using LINQ for further filtering might work, but it comes with its own set of trade-offs.

Your proposed approach can work, but you need to carefully weigh the trade-offs and consider the specific requirements and constraints of your project. It might be worth testing the performance of both approaches with realistic data volumes to see how they perform in your specific scenario. Additionally, consider if there are any alternative data access technologies or micro-ORMs that might provide a balance between performance and maintainability for your project.