# How can I use Dapper and X.PagedList (for pagination) which needs IQueryable together?

Tags: c#, dapper

I want to use Dapper with the most popular pagination package on Nuget - X.PagedList.

Here is an example usage of X.PagedList from their website:
[image]

It needs IQueryable but Dapper returns IEnumerable:

```
var posts = await _dbConnection.QueryAsync<PostDTO>(
    "SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE Title LIKE @SearchTerm",
    new
    {
        SearchTerm = "%" + request.SearchTerm + "%"
    });
```

How can I solve that problem?

- AsQueryable() isn't a solution
- not using Dapper isn't a solution because it protects against SQL injection

Comment: Basically, your question is "how to get IQueryable from dapper?". This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27563096/5779732).

Comment: Dapper do not generate query for you; so it is highly unlikely that you get this feature from Dapper. Many full ORMs provide protection against SQL Injection; you may choose other ORM. Some extensions of Dapper (Dapper-Extensions, Dapper-Contrib etc) use Dapper internally; see if any of it expose IQueryable.

Comment: Better thing to think about: should you be using Rowset Pagination anyway? It's really inefficient, it's much better to use Keyset Pagination.