# How to bind a DataSource to DataGridView or ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I am using the three layered architecture with Entity Framework 6.1 Code-First

Code in UI Layer

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = _userBLL.GetUsers();
```

Code in Business Logic Layer

```
public object GetUsers()
{
    return _userDAL.GetUsers();
}
```

Code in Data Access Layer

```
public object GetUsers()
{
    return db.Users.Select(u => u);
}
```

I can retrieve the data but while assigning the `DataSource` to `DataGridView` throwing below error:

> Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery, DbRawSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList(). For ASP.NET WebForms you can bind to the result of calling ToList() on the query or use Model Binding, for more information see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=389592.

Can anyone help me with this error? How can I assign a retrieved data source to a `DataGridView` as well as to a `ListView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `ToList()` method. Like this:

```
public object GetUsers()
{
   return db.Users.ToList();
}
```

Also you can use `AsQueryable()` like this: (Returning `IQueryable<T>` will defer execution of the query until its results are actually used.)

```
public IQueryable<User> GetUsers()
{
   return db.Users.AsQueryable();
}
```

Read this post may be useful: [`Why use AsQueryable() instead of List()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106802/why-use-asqueryable-instead-of-list)

Comment: Thanks.. ToList() works for me... Can you also let me know, how could I assign this data source to `ListView` ?

Comment: You cannot actually bind to a ListView control, as it does not support binding.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... so i this case how could we show the retrieved data in `ListView` control?

Answer (score 0):

you need to do like this

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
{
    return db.Users.Select(u => u).ToList();
}
```

Apply ToList and also change your return type as in code....You are having problem with your code because you are direcly biding query to your datagrid...This problem cause because linq queries are defferly executed.. that means you need to get result of query by using ToList, Count etc..