# Why is Entity Framework's AsEnumerable() downloading all data from the server?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

What is the explanation for EF downloading all result rows when `AsEnumerable()` is used?

What I mean is that this code:

```
context.Logs.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Id % 2 == 0).Take(100).ToList();
```

will download all the rows from the table before passing any row to the `Where()` method and there could be millions of rows in the table.

What I would like it to do, is to download only enough to gather 100 rows that would satisfy the `Id % 2 == 0` condition (most likely just around 200 rows).

Couldn't EF do on demand loading of rows like you can with plain ADO.NET using `Read()` method of `SqlDataReader` and save time and bandwidth?

I suppose that it does not work like that for a reason and I'd like to hear a good argument supporting that design decision.

**NOTE**: This is a completely contrived example and I know normally you should not use EF this way, but I found this in some existing code and was just surprised my assumptions turned out to be incorrect.

Comment: Why are you using `AsEnumerable()` at this point anyway ?

Comment: As I stated in the question, it is a contrived example, I know it is not what you should normally do and what I want to know is an argument behind such design decision rather than lazy fetching or rows from the server like you can do with SqlDataReader.

Comment: @cosmo0: why did you remove the information about EF version? EF7 is already in beta now and they might change the behavior in the future, right?

Comment: It's not EF-related, it's just logic. See my updated answer for that. It has even nothing to do with EF, I think.

Answer (score 20):

**The short answer:** The reason for the different behaviors is that, when you use `IQueryable` directly, a single SQL query can be formed for your entire LINQ query; but when you use `IEnumerable`, the entire table of data must be loaded.

**The long answer:** Consider the following code.

```
context.Logs.Where(x => x.Id % 2 == 0)
```

`context.Logs` is of type `IQueryable<Log>`. `IQueryable<Log>.Where` is taking an `Expression<Func<Log, bool>>` as the predicate. The `Expression` represents an abstract syntax tree; that is, it's more than just code you can run. Think of it as being represented in memory, at runtime, like this:

```
Lambda (=>)
  Parameters
    Variable: x
  Body
    Equals (==)
      Modulo (%)
        PropertyAccess (.)
          Variable: x
          Property: Id
        Constant: 2
      Constant: 0
```

The LINQ-to-Entities engine can take `context.Logs.Where(x => x.Id % 2 == 0)` and mechanically convert it into a SQL query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM "Logs"
WHERE "Logs"."Id" % 2 = 0;
```

If you change your code to `context.Logs.Where(x => x.Id % 2 == 0).Take(100)`, the SQL query becomes something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM "Logs"
WHERE "Logs"."Id" % 2 = 0
LIMIT 100;
```

This is entirely because the LINQ extension methods on `IQueryable` use `Expression` instead of just `Func`.

Now consider `context.Logs.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Id % 2 == 0)`. The `IEnumerable<Log>.Where` extension method is taking a `Func<Log, bool>` as a predicate. That is only runnable code. It cannot be analyzed to determine its structure; it cannot be used to form a SQL query.

Comment: Excellent and very complete explanation using a concrete example.

Answer (score 5):

Entity Framework and Linq use lazy loading. It means (among other things) that they will not run the query until they need to enumerate the results: for instance using `ToList()` or `AsEnumerable()`, or if the result is used as an enumerator (in a `foreach` for instance).

Instead, it builds a query using predicates, and returns `IQueryable` objects to further "pre-filter" the results before actually returning them. You can find more infos [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/giving-clarity-to-linq-queries-by-extending-expressions/) for instance. Entity framework will actually build a SQL query depending on the predicates you have passed it.

In your example:

```
context.Logs.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Id % 2 == 0).Take(100).ToList();
```

From the Logs table in the context, it fetches all, returns a `IEnumerable` with the results, then filters the result, takes the first 100, then lists the results as a `List`.

On the other hand, just removing the `AsEnumerable` solves your problem:

```
context.Logs.Where(x => x.Id % 2 == 0).Take(100).ToList();
```

Here it will build a query/filter on the result, then only once the `ToList()` is executed, query the database.

It also means that you can dynamically build a complex query without actually running it on the DB it until the end, for instance:

```
var logs = context.Logs.Where(a); // first filter
if (something) {
    logs = logs.Where(b); // second filter
}
var results = logs.Take(100).ToList(); // only here is the query actually executed
```

## Update

As mentionned in your comment, you seem to already know what I just wrote, and are just asking for a reason.

It's even simpler: since `AsEnumerable` casts the results to another type (a `IQueryable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` in this case), it has to convert all the results rows first, so it has to fetch the data first. It's basically a `ToList` in this case.

Comment: Good explanation!

Answer (score 5):

Clearly, you understand why it's better to avoid using `AsEnumerable()` the way you do in your question.

Also, some of the other answers have made it very clear ***why*** calling `AsEnumerable()` changes the way the query is performed and read. In short, it's because you are then invoking `IEnumrable<T>` extension methods rather than the `IQueryable<T>` extension methods, the latter allowing you to combine predicates ***before*** executing the query in the database.

However, I still feel that this doesn't answer your actual question, which is a legitimate question.  You said (emphasis mine):

> What I mean is that this code:
>
> `context.Logs.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Id % 2 == 0).Take(100).ToList();`
>
> will download ***all the rows*** from the table before passing any row to the `Where()` method and there could be millions of rows in the table.

My question to you is: *what made you conclude that this is true?*

I would argue that, because you are using `IEnumrable<T>` instead of `IQueryable<T>`, it's true that the query being performed in the database will be a simple:

```
select * from logs
```

... without any predicates, unlike what would have happened if you had used `IQueryable<T>` to invoke `Where` and `Take`.

However, the `AsEnumerable()` method call does ***not*** fetch all the rows at that moment, as other answers have implied.  In fact, this is the implementation of the `AsEnumerable()` call:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> AsEnumerable<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    return source;
}
```

There is no fetching going on there. In fact, even the calls to `IEnumerable<T>.Where()` and `IEnumerable<T>.Take()` don't actually start fetching any rows at that moment.  They simply setup wrapping `IEnumerable`s that will filter results as they are iterated on.  The fetching and iterating of the results really only begins when `ToList()` is called.

So when you say:

> Couldn't EF do on demand loading of rows like you can with plain ADO.NET using `Read()` method of `SqlDataReader` and save time and bandwidth?

... again, my question to you would be: *doesn't it do that already?*

If your table had `1,000,000` rows, I would still expect your code snippet to only fetch up to `100` rows that satisfy your `Where` condition, and then stop fetching rows.

To prove the point, try running the following little program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = PretendImAOneMillionRecordTable().Where(i => i < 500).Take(10).ToList();
}

private static IEnumerable<int> PretendImAOneMillionRecordTable()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("fetching {0}", i);
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

... when I run it, I only get the following 10 lines of output:

```
fetching 0
fetching 1
fetching 2
fetching 3
fetching 4
fetching 5
fetching 6
fetching 7
fetching 8
fetching 9
```

It doesn't iterate through the whole set of `1,000,000` "rows" even though I am chaining `Where()` and `Take()` calls on `IEnumerable<T>`.

Now, you do have to keep in mind that, for your little EF code snippet, if you test it using a very small table, it may actually fetch ***all*** the rows at once, if all the rows fit within the value for [SqlConnection.PacketSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.packetsize(v=vs.110).aspx).  This is normal.  Every time `SqlDataReader.Read()` is called, it never only fetches a single row at a time.  To reduce the amount of network call roundtrips, it will always try to fetch a batch of rows at a time.  I wonder if this is what you observed, and this mislead you into thinking that `AsEnumerable()` was causing ***all*** rows to be fetched from the table.

Even though you will find that your example doesn't perform nearly as bad as you thought, this would not be a reason not to use `IQueryable`.  Using `IQueryable` to construct more complex database queries will almost always provide better performance, because you can then benefit from database indexes, etc to fetch results more efficiently.

Comment: I'm genuinely confused, some people like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet/2876655#2876655 say that AsEnumerable will load all the data into memory and then filters them etc... (in fact not only that answer, many other answers on stackoverflow say the same thing) but then your answer says that it doesn't load all the data into memory and THEN filter or whatever... what's the truth? does it load all the data into memory or not.

Comment: Btw, is there any Microsoft docs to read about the real differences between the AsEnumerable and AsQueryable? I searched but I didn't find anything useful. they were not related to whether it loads them into memory or not... I don't know what to search for tbh.

Comment: @bzmind: The wording in the post you linked is a little confusing, but I assure you that he meant the same thing, which is why he says that "both will give you deferred execution". In short, IQueryable enables filtering at the database level BEFORE data is read in memory, where as IEnumerable can only filter data that is read in memory. However, this does not mean that the COMPLETE SET of data will be read in memory before any filtering is applied.  IEnumerable is able to apply the filtering in memory progressively as the data is read in memory little by little.

Answer (score 0):

`AsEnumerable()` eagerly loads the `DbSet<T>` `Logs`

You probably want something like

```
context.Logs.Where(x => x.Id % 2 == 0).AsEnumerable();
```

The idea here is that you're applying a predicate filter to the collection before actually loading it from the database.

An impressive subset of the world of LINQ is supported by EF. It will translate your beautiful LINQ queries into SQL expressions behind the scenes.

Comment: The question is why the DbSet<T> is eagerly loaded in this case? Does it have to be?

Comment: `DbSet<T>` is not loaded eagerly on its own. It offers an `IQueryable<T>`-ish interface. It implements `IEnumerable<T>`, which may be the nugget of knowledge you're missing here.

Comment: Anothe way to put it: `AsEnumerable()` is not needed to make the collection "enumerable". `DbSet<T>` is already "enumerable".

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this before.
The context command is not executed until a linq function is called, because you have done

```
context.Logs.AsEnumerable()
```

it has assumed you have finished with the query and therefore compiled it and returns all rows.
If you changed this to:

```
context.Logs.Where(x => x.Id % 2 == 0).AsEnumerable()
```

It would compile a SQL statement that would get only the rows where the id is modular 2.
Similarly if you did

```
context.Logs.Where(x => x.Id % 2 == 0).Take(100).ToList();
```

that would create a statement that would get the top 100...

I hope that helps.

Comment: I do understand how it works but I'd like to know why it works this way rather the other way I described in the question.

Comment: Well, your assumption of "lazily" loading the data means that after you have written your linq query it then goes to the database and pulls back only the records you are interested in.
The thing is, that is exactly what is happening. The only problem you have, is to remember to use the linq functions at the end of your expression because that function is what tells EF to compile the SQL script.

Answer (score 0):

LinQ to Entities has a store expression formed by all the Linq methods before It goes to an enumeration.

When you use AsEnumerable() and then Where() like this:

`context.Logs.Where(...).AsEnumerable()`

The Where() knows that the previous chain call has a store expression so he appends his predicate to It for lazy loading.

The overload of Where that is being called is different if you call this:

```
context.Logs.AsEnumerable().Where(...)
```

Here the Where() only knows that his previous method is an enumeration (it could be any kind of "enumerable" collection) and the only way that he can apply his condition is iterating over the collection with the IEnumerable implementation of the DbSet class, which must to retrieve the records from the database first.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you should ever use this:

```
context.Logs.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Id % 2 == 0).Take(100).ToList();
```

The correct way of doing things would be:

```
context.Logs.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Id % 2 == 0).Take(100).ToList();
```

Answer with explanations here:

- [What's the difference(s) between .ToList(), .AsEnumerable(), AsQueryable()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968469/whats-the-differences-between-tolist-asenumerable-asqueryable)
- [Why use AsQueryable() instead of List()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106802/why-use-asqueryable-instead-of-list)

Comment: to be honest, why even use AsQueryable? I mean the context.Logs entity set is already cast as IQueryable

Comment: I know what the correct way is, the point of the question is why it cannot work the other way I described.

Comment: Because I don't know whether that is a DbSet<Entity> to assume otherwise.

Comment: @PiotrOwsiak Because is not optimum to work like that. It will take you time and memory to get that data back.

Comment: @Floradu88: I believe fetching whole table in this case is less optimum than fetching enough rows to satisfy the condition (which would most likely be around 200 rows). Thus I'm really surprised my assumption was wrong.