# Return IQueryable or IEnumerable What Happens?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, collections

As far as I understand, **IQueryable** is a query that has not been executed yet, and the filter conditions like `.Where(x=> x != 3)` are added to the SQL query and get the final result when executed. **IEnumerable**, on the other hand, first takes all the data and puts it into the memory, the filtering is done over all the data in the memory.

1. If IEnumerable takes the data and puts it into memory, is the query executed?
2. So why is it said to be executed when using methods like `.Count()` if the **IEnumerable** has already run and dumped the data into memory?
3. Why do we do `.Count()` and not `.Count` like **List** type?

```
public IEnumerable<Number> GetNumbers()
{            
     IQueryable<Number> result = _context
         .Numbers
         .Where(x => x != 3);
     return result;
}
```

4. In the above code, the `result` is of type IQueryable, but IEnumerable returned from the method. What kind of operation takes place here, while a query that hasn't been executed yet, is the query executed and thrown into memory when the return statement is executed?

Comment: If you call `GetNumbers()` still nothing happens. The only difference from returning `IQueryable` is that the `IQueryable` inside the method can't be extend any more. It's a question of opinion (or considerations we can't make for you) whether that's good or not.

Comment: _"What kind of operation takes place here"_ - nothing apart from a upcast, `IQueryable<T>` inherits `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: You don't modify the type, but the information is lost that it's `IQueryable`, so from now on you will use Linq-To-Objects. It is similar to using `AsEnumerable` in between the query. So for example  if you'd use then `GetNumbers().Where(SomeFilter)`, then `SomeFilter` is executed in memory and you are not limited to something that can be translated to sql.

Comment: `var numbers= GetNumbers();` 
Is the value that comes as a result of this code a query waiting to be executed or has it already been executed and thrown into memory?

Comment: A query waiting to be executed. A "promise", or as .NET calls it, "deferred execution". The IEnumerable contains everything your code needs to _materialize_ the results, but not the results themselves, yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I understand, `IQueryable` is a query that has not been executed yet, and the filter conditions like `.Where(x=> x != 5)` are added to the SQL query and get the final result when executed.

Yes, you understanding is correct (in case if you are working with queryable provider which performs such translation).

> `IEnumerable`, on the other hand, first takes all the data and puts it into the memory, the filtering is done over all the data in the memory

Yes, exactly (with small but important nitpick, that `IEnumerable` is also lazy and all of that will be performed only when materialization happens like with `.Count()`, `foreach`, `ToList` etc.)

> What kind of operation takes place here, while a query that hasn't been executed yet

As mentioned in the "nitpick" part earlier - nothing will happen here, but when `GetNumbers(). SomeEnumOps .Count()` will be called, it will fetch all the data client side, perform "SomeEnumOps" in-memory and then do the counting. Basically it will have the same effect like calling [`AsEnumerable` over queryable in EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837028/why-is-entity-frameworks-asenumerable-downloading-all-data-from-the-server)

Notes:

- [`IQueryable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable-1?view=net-8.0) is `IEnumerable<T>`

  ```
  public interface IQueryable<out T> : IEnumerable<out T>, IQueryable
  ```
- From [`Enumerable.AsEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.asenumerable?view=net-8.0) docs:

  > The `AsEnumerable<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)` method has no effect other than to change the compile-time type of source from a type that implements `IEnumerable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` itself.
  > `AsEnumerable<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)` can be used to choose between query implementations when a sequence implements `IEnumerable<T>` but also has a different set of public query methods available. For example, given a generic class `Table` that implements `IEnumerable<T>` and has its own methods such as `Where`, `Select`, and `SelectMany`, a call to `Where` would invoke the public `Where` method of `Table`. A `Table` type that represents a database table could have a `Where` method that takes the predicate argument as an expression tree and converts the tree to SQL for remote execution. If remote execution is not desired, for example because the predicate invokes a local method, the `AsEnumerable` method can be used to hide the custom methods and instead make the standard query operators available.

Bonus.

> Why do we do `.Count()` and not `.Count` like `List` type?

Because LINQ is based on extension methods (like [`Queryable.Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.count?view=net-8.0)) and you can't have extension properties in C# ATM.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Which would be the correct approach to return IQueryable or IEnumerable from the repository method in the EF repository pattern?

Comment: @MrAlbino this can be a bit controversial but quite a lot of people consider abstracting over EF with repository/UoW as an anti-pattern ([for example](https://bigmachine.io/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/)). In my personal opinion if you decide to use repositories over EF you should not expose the `IQueryable` because it actually leaks the abstraction making it almost useless. As for filtering - I prefer returning something like `ICollection` and making methods to accept specification (see the specification pattern) or bunch of filtering parameters based on use case