# Is AsQueryAble() Method Takes All Data From Database (MongoDB)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb, .net-core

I have IMongoCollection variable which is "_collection".

```
public IQueryable<T> GetBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
{
    if (predicate != null)
    {
        return _collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Status > 0).Where(predicate);
    }
    else
    {
        return _collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Status > 0);
    }
}
```

in ASP.NET Core

Are the records coming when i call the .AsQueryAble() method ? Or do we have to call .ToList() or something like this method to get records from database (MongoDB)

Comment: maybe this will give you a little information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106802/why-use-asqueryable-instead-of-list

Comment: you are my hero. that's answer what i want!! that saves me now.